# In case of Django model,

Tags: python, django

In the django code in order to make a model,

for example,

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
```

Why models.CharField(max_length = 200). Why can't we write only `name=CharField(max_length = 200)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can**. You should only import that field in the scope, for example with:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import CharField  # 🖘 import CharField

class Student(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=200)  # 🖘 use CharField
```

The field classes like `CharField`, `IntegerField`, … are all members of the `django.db.models` module, so you can import these in the head of the file.

You can also import `Model` and thus work with:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import CharField, Model  # 🖘 import Model

class Student(Model):  # 🖘 use Model
    name = CharField(max_length=200)
```

Comment: if Charfield is a class of models then what is the purpose of inheriting Model as models.Model

Comment: @Shiro: Django's `models` module also exports `Model`. The meta-class logic of `Model` will register the fields, such that Django can make migrations and make queries according to the defintions in that model. But you can also import `from django.db.models import Model`, and thus write `Student(Model):`.